# Get the latest record or the first transaction (sale) BigQuery SQL standard

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table on BigQuery with the following columns:

```
user_id visit_date  referral    transaction
1234    20180101    site2       0
1234    20180102    site3       1
1234    20180103    site2       1
4567    20180104    site4       0
4567    20180105    site5       0
5678    20180101    site2       0
5768    20180102    site3       1
```

My goal is to have a table in the following format as output:

```
path                transactions
site2 > site3       2 
site2               1
site4 > site5       0
```

What I don't understand is how to 'reset' the path for a user that have multiple conversions in the same period, as is the case for user_id = 1234.

So far I manage use the following query, but it is not the desired output.

```
SELECT
  referral_path,
  SUM(transactions) AS transactions
FROM (
  SELECT
  user_id,
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(referral), ',') AS referral_path,
  MAX(transactions) AS transactions
  FROM (
     SELECT
     user_id,
     referral,
     transactions
  FROM
     table
  ORDER BY
     user_id )a
  GROUP BY
     user_id )b
  GROUP BY
     referral_path
  ORDER BY
      transactions DESC
```

Comment: what you mean by `reset` the path - please explain more. also do you allow only two referrals in the path?

Comment: It could have more than 2 referrals. By reset I mean, for the first user (id=1234) for the same period, it has 2 conversions, after the first conversion, the path should restart from site2. Instead of being site2 > site3 > site2.

Comment: tnx. i see. got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  path, 
  SUM(transaction) transactions
FROM (
  SELECT
    STRING_AGG(referral, ' > ') path,
    SUM(transaction) transaction
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id, visit_date, referral, transaction, 
      IFNULL(SUM(transaction) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY visit_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) grp 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
  GROUP BY user_id, grp
)
GROUP BY path
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1234 user_id, '20180101' visit_date, 'site2' referral, 0 transaction UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, '20180102', 'site3', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, '20180103', 'site2', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, '20180104', 'site4', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, '20180105', 'site5', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5678, '20180101', 'site2', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5678, '20180102', 'site3', 1 
)
SELECT 
  path, 
  SUM(transaction) transactions
FROM (
  SELECT
    STRING_AGG(referral, ' > ') path,
    SUM(transaction) transaction
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id, visit_date, referral, transaction, 
      IFNULL(SUM(transaction) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY visit_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) grp 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
  GROUP BY user_id, grp
)
GROUP BY path
ORDER BY transactions DESC
```

with result

```
Row path            transactions     
1   site2 > site3   2    
2   site2           1    
3   site4 > site5   0
```

Comment: The solution works fine! I just don't understand "1 PRECEDING" command at the end of the over function. So within a specific user_id, It goes from unbounded preceding (the first one row) to the last?

Comment: that's correct. this logic catches when group value is changed so then you can use grp in GROUP BY - I recommend you to run inner queries one by one to see how it works - so you will be able to use this approach by your own :o)